# Unable to assign the selected value from database to dropdown using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Hello all I want to show selected value in dropdown based on the value fetch from the database in angularjs. I am trying the basic functionality where I am setting ng-model value to the dropdown after fetch it from database. But it is not working for me. Its always show me blank dropdown.

My dropdown structure

```
 <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="measurements.Backzip" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">--Select --</option>
                                <option ng-repeat="sel in selectables" value="{{sel.value}}">{{sel.label}}</option>
                            </select>
```

My code for fetch the data from database and assign value to measurements.Backzip

Firstly I have declared the variables

```
 $scope.measurements = {};
$scope.measurements.Backzip = "";
```

Then After this I create this function

```
 function GetDetails() {

        $scope.selectables = [
       { label: 'Yes', value: 'true'},
       { label: 'NO', value: 'false' } 
        ];

        $scope.getemail = store.get('usersession');

        var productResult = customerService.getMeasurementDetails($scope.getemail);
        productResult.then(function (result) {
            if (!result.data) {
                console.log("empty");
            }
            else { 
                store.set("mvalues", result.data);
                $scope.measurements = result.data;
                $scope.measurements.Backzip = result.data.Backzip;
                console.log("zip",result.data.Backzip);

            }
        });
    };
```

Json output from my api

```
{"id":2,"userid":null,"Height":3,"Kameezlength":3,"Shoulder":3,"SleeveLength":3,"SleeveMoori":3,"Armhole"
:3,"Chest":3,"Waist":3,"Hip":3,"KameezGhera":3,"Chalk":3,"FrontNeck":3,"BackNeck":1,"BackDori":3,"Backzip"
:false,"Plates":3,"SalwarLength":3,"SalwarHalfPatiala":null,"SalwarFullPatiala":null,"SalwarPouncha"
:3,"SalwarAssan":3,"SalwarBelt":3,"PazamiLength":32,"PazamiChurridaar":null,"PazamiThigh":3,"PazamiKnee"
:3,"PazamiMoori":3,"PazamiAssan":3,"PazamiBelt":3,"useremail":"azadrchauhan@gmail.com"}
```

Data is fetching succesfully here.But I am unable to assign the selected value to dropdown. Can anybody help. I tried almost every example from stackoveflow. But nothing works. Maybe I am missing anything

Comment: Try to manually set the value and see if that changes it: `$scope.measurements.Backzip = 'true';`

Comment: yes it is changing @QuetiM.Porta

Comment: So it's probably related to what you are getting back from the server

Comment: in sqlserver its getting data from bit datatype column its true and false @QuetiM.Porta

Comment: Take a look at @Lex's answer. You are getting back a boolean value, but in the `$scope.selectables`, you've defined the `value` as a string. Simply define the `value` in `$scope.selectables` without the quotes and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the classic issue of trying to assign a value to a select that is not a string. Fortunately, Angular has the perfect construct to address this in `ng-options`.

Change your HTML to this:

```
<select 
    name="singleSelect"
    ng-model="measurements.Backzip"
    class="form-control"
    ng-options="option.value as option.label for option in selectables">
</select>
```

And then change the code in your controller to this:

```
$scope.selectables = [
    { label: '--Select--'},
    { label: 'Yes', value: true},
    { label: 'NO', value: false }];
```

** Update: Added the default '--Select--' option from the original.

Comment: Not working how? Perhaps the value of `measurements.Backzip` is not a boolean?

Comment: its boolean. from sqlserver bit type column its getting values

Comment: Can you post the value of `result.data`?

Comment: check I update my question with the output which I am getting from api @QuetiM.Porta

Comment: Try removing the `$scope.measurements.Backzip = "";` line from your controller.

Comment: thanks its work :) silly mistake from my side.. but anyways thanks for help @Lex